# CQ5 - Cannot Search for Asset Substring

Tags: aem

I noticed that CQ5 cannot find some assets if I were to search for part of the substring. For example:

Library of assets:
black_ball_500x200.jpg
white_ball_500x200.jpg
black_white_ball_500x200.jpg

If I were to search for 'white', CQ5 returned the following:
white_ball_500x200.jpg
black_white_ball_500x200.jpg

If I were to search for '500x200', CQ5 returned the following:
black_ball_500x200.jpg
white_ball_500x200.jpg
black_white_ball_500x200.jpg

However, if I were to search for part of a substring such as '500' or 'whit', or 'lack', CQ5 would return nothing.

It seems that CQ5 uses underscores in file names to create seperate searchable terms for each file. This becomes a problem for me especially if I want to look for only asstes 500px wide and CQ5 returns nothing. Unfortunately changing the naming structure of all my assets is not an option. I am wondering if there is a fix to this?

Comment: Are you searching the DAM via the search tab (i.e.     
      http://localhost:4502/damadmin)

Answer (score 0):

try using '*' as part of your search string

Comment: `*` is not an option for me. I'm trying to make this as simple as possible for the guys using the CMS.